# Error: Strict Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: magento-1.9, php, error, log, ce-1.9.2.2

My log file show error:

```
2016-02-19T04:20:31+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference  in /home/..../controllers/IndexController.php on line 17

2016-02-19T04:20:31+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given  in /home/.../controllers/IndexController.php on line 18


$path=explode('index/index/path/',array_shift(explode('?',@$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));<br>
$ex = explode('/id/', $path);
```

Please tell me how can fix!

Answer (score 0):

you also should explain what you want to achieve actually, but I can at least try to resolve your errors:

you are not allowed to pass the explode result directly to the array_shift function. This is because array_shift manipulates the array and using the result of explode, there is no variable where this change can be saved in.

```
$requestUri = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$path=explode('index/index/path/',array_shift($requestUri);
```

The second error is simply that `$path` is an array, but explode needs a string. To solve this I would need to know what you are trying to do here?